# Clicked Links disappear

Tags: html, twine

I have some very simple code:

```
Thing (link: "Look at")[(alert: [This is some text], "Sure.")]
```

Every time I click the link, it correctly displays the dialog, but the link itself disappears. I have been reading the Twine/Harlowe forums and I see people asking for this functionality, but for some reason I cant NOT do it.

I just want it to stay there, so I can keep clicking it as much as I like.
Nothing in the Documentation says anything about it disappearing.
This happens even in a brand new Story with no CSS or any other passages or variables.

How can I make it NOT go away after clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, quite simple in the end. It's NOT the **link** macro I should have been using. Instead I should have been using the **link-rerun** macro. Here is my working code:

```
Thing (link-rerun: "Look at")[(alert: [Its a thing], "Sure.")]
```